# Cloning a C# Reference Type to a Derived Reference Type

Tags: c#, clone, reference-type

Coming from a C++ background, I am finding cloning of objects in C# a little hard to get used to. To clear up some of my confusion, I am looking for an elegant way to clone an object of a base type to a derived type.

To illustrate:

```
public class Base
{
    public string Member1;
    public int Member2;
    public float Member3;
    public bool Member4;
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public List<Base> Children;
}

Base base = new Base();
```

And with that I want to create an instance of "Derived" whilst doing a memberwise copy of the Base object - preferably without assigning them manually.

Note: Maybe this would be more suited to a value type?

Comment: Sounds like an odd thing to do, to me. Care to provide more context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't change the type of an object, you have a few options:

- *encapsulate* `Base`
- use a constructor that copies the values from `Base`
- copy the properties from `Base` through reflection or similar

For the latter, [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) has a helpful tool:

```
Base b= ...
Derived item = PropertyCopy<Derived>.CopyFrom(b);
```

For encapsulation:

```
public class Derived
{
    readonly Base b;
    public Derived(Base b) {this.b=b;}
    public List<Base> Children;
    public string Member1 {get {return b.Member1;} set {...} }
    public int Member2 {etc}
    public float Member3 {etc}
    public bool Member4 {etc}
}
```

Or as a manual copy:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(Base b) {
        this.Member1 = b.Member1;
        // etc
    }
    // additional members...
}
```

or (comments) get the base to copy itself:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(Base b) : base(b) { }
    // additional members...
}
public class Base
{
    // members not shown...
    public Base() {}
    protected Base(Base b) {
       this.Member1 = b.Member1;
        // etc
    }
    // additional members...
}
```

(where `Base`'s constructor initializes the fields from `Base`)

Comment: You can improve the "manual copy" version by using copy constructors - this way you can ask `Base` to create a copy of itself, and it can play with its privates as well, if needed - it also works if there is more than one derived class from it.

Answer (score 2):

```
/// Clone all fields from an instance of base class TSrc into derived class TDst
public static TDst Clone<TSrc, TDst>(TSrc source, TDst target)
    where TDst : TSrc
{
    var bf = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
    foreach (FieldInfo fis in source.GetType().GetFields(bf))
        fis.SetValue(target, fis.GetValue(source));
    return target;
}

/// Create a new instance of a derived class, cloning all fields from type TSrc
public static TDst Clone<TSrc, TDst>(TSrc source)
    where TDst : TSrc, new()
{
    return Clone(source, new TDst());
}
```